# Need return to match what print is showing me

Tags: python, python-3.x, return, repr

I need return to give what the last print line is giving me.
At the bottom I have invoked class with values. Also, pointers to improve the code are welcome.

```
class Building:
    def __init__(self, south, west, width_WE, width_NS, height=10):
        # making variables non-local
        self.south=int(south)
        self.west=int(west)
        self.width_WE=int(width_WE)
        self.width_NS=int(width_NS)
        self.height=height
        self.d={}
        self.d['north-east']=(south+width_NS,west+width_WE) 
        self.d['south-east']=(south,west+width_WE)
        self.d['south-west']=(south,west)
        self.d['north-west']=(south+width_NS,west)
        self.wwe=width_WE
        self.wns=width_NS
        self.height=10
    def corner(self):  # gives co-ordinates of the corners
        print(self.d)
    def area (self):    # gives area
        print(self.wwe*self.wns)
        return(self.wwe*self.wns)
    def volume(self):   #gives volume
        print(self.wwe*self.wns*self.height)
    def __repr__(self):     # I dont know what to call it but answer should be''Building(10, 10, 1, 2, 2)''
        print ("Building(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"%(self.south, self.west, self.width_WE, self.width_NS,"10"))
        #return ("Building(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"%(self.south, self.west, self.width_WE, self.width_NS,"10"))

abc = Building(10, 10, 1, 2, 2)
abc.corner()
abc.area()
abc.volume()
```

Comment: And what do you get instead? Note that `str.format` is more modern, and you should probably be using `%r` to get the representation of the arguments.

Comment: That helped along with some other changes. Now I am having a different problem. :/

Comment: yep, well, welcome to programming. Just solve each little problem and eventually there'll be none left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `__str__` instead:

```
    def __str__(self):
      return "Building({0},{1},{2},{3},{4})".format(self.south, self.west, self.width_WE, self.width_NS,"10")
    def __repr__(self):        
      __str__()
```

Also you should probably not be setting `height` explicitly if you're going to pass it in as an argument:

```
    ...
    self.height=10
    ...
```

Should read:

```
    ...
    self.height=height
    ...
```

Comment: I need to specify it when test cases only pass 4 arguments.  When they pass all 5 then I want height to assume the 5th value. Else go with 10 as default. That is the problem I am having now.

Comment: Having `height=10` in your constructor arguments does exactly that. You don't need to set it to 10 explicitly inside the constructor. And I noticed that for some reason you are initializing `self.height` twice. Just keep the first `self.height = height` and remove the `self.height = 10`. That should give you the behavior you're looking for.

Comment: Also, please do remember to mark this answer as CORRECT if the solution worked for you. :)